# solving time with the given distance and acceleration

Tags: calculus

A driver traveling at $140 ^{\text{km}}/_{\text{hr}}$ along a straight hi-way. He sees a dog and applies the brake and the car is slowing down at $15 ^{\text{km}}/_{\text{hr}^2}$. How long does it takes to reach speed limit of $100 ^{\text{km}}/_{\text{hr}}$?

Comment: since the deceleration is constant the speed at time $t$ is given by $v(t)=140-15\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}^2} t$ if you put in $v=100\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}}$ you can solve this for t. (solve $100=140-15t$ for $t$, the solution is in hrs, you probably have to convert it to some other time scale)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question stated, the steps are really simple. Look:

- Initial velocity $140\frac{\text km}{\text h}$
- Final velocity $100\frac {\text km}{\text h}$
- Constant rate of deceleration $15\frac{\text km}{\text h^2}$

So all you do is take the difference between the two velocities and divide by the deceleration to see how much time is spent to reach the final velocity. It should intuitively make sense to you.

$$t = \frac{(140-100)\frac{\text km}{\text h}}{15 \frac{\text km}{\text h^2}}\\
t = \frac{40}{15}\text h\\
t = \frac 8 3 \text h = 2\frac 2 3 \text h$$

However, I'm not sure that's what you're asking - the question title says given **distance** and acceleration, while the question gives **velocity** and acceleration - the steps to solve for the distance are more complicated.

Also, adding furthermore to my confusion is the lack of realism in the answer. Seriously, if it takes nearly 3 hours to slow down to the speed limit, you'd have run into the dog by long (not to mention how slowing down to the speed limit helps) - and you'd probably be pulled over by an officer long ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of motion under constant acceleration, for which you can use SUVAT- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#SUVAT_equations

We have: $$s=?, \ u=140, \ v=100, \ a=-15, \ t=?$$

We want to find $t$, so let's use the formula $$v=u+at.$$

Re-arrange this to give $$t=\frac{v-u}{a}=\boxed{??}.$$

Now I'll leave you to substitute the values into this equation to find $t$.